# can't scroll to the end of data kendo-ui-grid

Tags: scroll, virtual, kendo-ui-grid

I want to use kendo-ui-grid server paging with virtual scrolling and encountered a problem I don't know how to solve

It's shown in here:
http://dojo.telerik.com/uyEje

Try scrolling to row number 2M.

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Kendo UI documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#virtual-scrolling) ...

> "Virtual scrolling relies on a fake scrollbar. Its size is not determined by the browser, but is calculated based on the average row height of the data that is already loaded. As a result, variable row heights may cause unexpected behavior, such as inability to scroll to the last rows on the last page.  To ensure that all table rows have the same heights, use either of the options: (1) Disable text wrapping. (2) Set an explicit row height that is large enough (as demonstrated in the following example)."